# Why are my dwellers unhappy?

Tags: fallout-shelter

All of my health bars are green and full, none of the dwellers are injured and they all have jobs. I don't see what I'm doing wrong.

I've tried mating them and they are still unhappy.

Comment: Making babies helps a lot to make them happy ;)

Comment: [Bubble Bliss Baby](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/220240/) [says](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/259323): "I just had this same problem, where some dwellers were either training or working in the job of their highest stat, but were still unhappy. I gave them weapons, and now they are happy. Try that."

Answer (score 5):

The key to happiness is to send dwellers do the job they are good at. If they have the same stat on multiple things (S,P,A) then you train them. If they have charisma you create a radio room and make them work there.

If nothing works, sending them to the living quarters (the house of love) should clear any dark thoughts! :)

Also some of them might want to explore, especially the ones with high endurance.

**A good tip is to listen the people. If you zoom in the rooms, you will see them talking about stuff that bothers them or stuff they would prefer to do!**

Comment: like.. what kind of Pizza they like, what they should pain, how little books there are in the vault and asking themselves how it looks outside

Comment: Yeah, that... and... man, I would really like to love what I do... ever wondered how it is to be heard by many... it's so sad that I can't start a family because the vault is full... man, we are forced to work with dead people... what is that smell... is that a hand growing out of my stomach... etc

Comment: Be aware that sometimes that say things just for the point of saying something. What they say is not always an indication of what they need.

Answer (score 1):

If the dwellers have red on their health bar, they have radiation poisoning.

Give them a radaway, and they will be happy again.

Answer (score -1):

Job Satisfaction. Pair your dwellers with the *trabajos* of their primary SPECIAL stat.

I have found that some still aren't happy until they have seen what lies outside the vault. Afterward they are happy to toil in the water treatment plant. (Okay, not really a measurable improvement.)

Comment: What are **trabajos**?

Comment: :)) ... I think it was intended as a joke... trabajo is spanish for job.